# Free Pascal accepting MOVQ xmm, r

Tags: assembly, cpu-registers, freepascal

Per [this page](http://www.jaist.ac.jp/iscenter-new/mpc/altix/altixdata/opt/intel/vtune/doc/users_guide/mergedProjects/analyzer_ec/mergedProjects/reference_olh/mergedProjects/instructions/instruct32_hh/vc199.htm), MOVQ can accept the following:

```
MOVQ mm, mm/m64
Move quadword from mm/m64 to mm.

MOVQ mm/m64, mm
Move quadword from mm to mm/m64.

MOVQ xmm1, xmm2/m64
Move quadword from xmm2/mem64 to xmm1.

MOVQ xmm2/m64, xmm1
Move quadword from xmm1 to xmm2/mem64.
```

However, my Free Pascal compiler is accepting this:

```
MOVQ xmm1, rcx
```

This is a move from a register, which is supported my MOVD, not MOVQ.

Agner Fog's [instruction tables](http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf) concurs with the above definition.

Why is the compiler accepting this (and it's working)?

Comment: `Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual Volume 2 (2A, 2B & 2C): Instruction Set Reference, A-Z` has two sections on `MOVQ`, one is MOVQ without `r/m64`, the other is `MOVD/MOVQ` combined, with `r/m64`. The compiler is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in doubt always consult the official reference, not some obscure web page.
This is what the [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manual Volume 2 (2A, 2B & 2C): Instruction Set Reference, A-Z](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf)
says:

> 66 REX.W 0F 6E /r MOVQ xmm, r/m64 SSE2 Move quadword from r/m64 to
>   xmm.

So it's valid.